# Import global vs getStaticProps in Next/React Component

Tags: reactjs, import, fetch, next.js

So I'm new in Next.js and I'm wondering, in my index.js file in pages I have a component that will return a list from a JSON object. So whats the difference between importing this JSON file outside my component or getting it inside getStaticProps?

```
import contactList from '../../public/contactList.json'

export default function Home () {

// ... component here

}
```

OR

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

import contactList from '../../public/contactList.json'

return {

    props: {contactList}

    }

}

export default function Home () {

// ... component here

}
```

OR even i could instead set an environment variable in Vercel for using fetch.
Whats the pros and cons of each of these?

EDIT: I should use import(adress) inside getStaticProps, witch will return an object with the json "array" in a default param, so correcting myself:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

const list = await import ('../../public/contactList.json');

return {

    props: { contactList: list.default }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it boils down to better performance. From the [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) docs:

> Note: You can import modules in top-level scope for use in getStaticProps. Imports used in getStaticProps will not be bundled for the client-side.

So the data will be fetched at build time if you use the import in `getStaticProps` and the user accessing the website will have to download fewer data which will result in a faster page.

**EDIT:**
The Next.js docs explicitly state not to use `fetch` to get internal data:

> Note: You should not use fetch() to call an API route in getStaticProps. Instead, directly import the logic used inside your API route. You may need to slightly refactor your code for this approach.
> Fetching from an external API is fine!

Comment: Thank you very much, so the import outside getStaticProps will be run on every refresh at the client side, whereas the import inside will be run at buildtime on the server side, right? 
And what about using fetch instead of import? I see a lot of people coding with fetch (with the downside of having to set environment variables because fetch needs an absolute URL) but I remember reading someowhere that import is a better choice on performance because fetch makes http requests but import does not. So?

Comment: Basically yes, even if it is technically imprecise to say that it runs on every refresh, as the file is just in the resulting bundle of code. The code in getStaticProps is only performed once on build time. The next.js docs explicitly state that you should not use fetch for internal data. I will update my answer with it.